# Async error when I set WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am trying to create an WCF service. The service have to enter data in the database.But as soon I test it I get the error that my method is Async(). Why is that?

```
namespace Test1
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    void SetInsurance(InsuranceDetails insInfo);
}

[DataContract]
public class InsuranceDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public string company
    {
        get { return company; }
        set { company = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string ssno
    {
        get { return ssno; }
        set { ssno = value; }
    }
}
}

namespace Test1
{
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void SetInsurance(InsuranceDetails insInfo)
    {
        Console.Write(insInfo.ToString());
    } 
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide complete details of the exception including the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you . I don't have any exception just the error when I run with F5. I added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Here is an answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/26616224/920557

Comment: I googled before I asked and I sow this answer. How do I need to change my code?

Comment: Try to host your service on a console application. Create a client app (console or win form) that will call the service method. This Wcf Test Client sometimes doesnt work for me too.

Comment: Here is an excerpt from the answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/26616224/920557 "The "error" you are seeing is just a limitation of the test tool that comes with visual studio, both functions call the same server side function so there is no compelling force to make Microsoft add support. There is no actual error. If you really want to test the async version you will need to write your own test client that calls the function."